# Cumulative Sum in ClickHouse

Tags: sql, performance, clickhouse, cumulative-sum

I have clickhouse table with 3 columns: respondent, spot и weight.

Data looks like this:

```
resp, spot, weight
1, 10, 100
2, 10, 200
3, 10, 300
1, 10, 100
1, 20, 100
3, 20, 300
4, 20, 400
1, 30, 100
2, 30, 200
3, 30, 300
5, 30, 500
```

`spot` column is sorted.
I need to write a query to calculate the accumulated Weight for `Spots` in the order of 10, 20, 30 so that each respondent is counted only once.
That is, in `spot = 20` respondents that were in `spot = 10` should be taken into cumulative sum, but only once. In `spot = 30` respondents that were in `spot = 10` and `spot = 20` should be taken into cumulative sum, but only once.

The final result will be as follows:

```
spot, summed_weight
10, 600
20, 1000
30, 1500
```

I tried to use `group_array` function to combine respondent and its weight, and found last rows per spot via `row_number` function, but RAM consumption had become extremely high.
Something like this:

```
resp, spot, weight, group_array, row_number
1, 10, 100, [(1,100)], 4
2, 10, 200, [(1,100), (2,200)], 3
3, 10, 300, [1,100), (2,200), (3,300)], 2
1, 10, 100, [1,100), (2,200), (3,300)], 1
1, 20, 100, [1,100), (2,200), (3,300)], 3
3, 20, 300, [1,100), (2,200), (3,300)], 2
4, 20, 400, [1,100), (2,200), (3,300), (4,400)], 1
1, 30, 100, [1,100), (2,200), (3,300), (4,400)], 4
2, 30, 200, [1,100), (2,200), (3,300), (4,400)], 3
3, 30, 300, [1,100), (2,200), (3,300), (4,400)], 2
5, 30, 500, [1,100), (2,200), (3,300), (4,400), (5,500)], 1
```

Comment: I'll add a reply below but always provide your current SQL query if you can + schema + INSERT. Makes it easier for everyone

Comment: Based on your description its hard to see how spot 20 has a result of 1000


`10 = 100 (resp 1) +200 (resp 2) +300 (resp 3) = 600` so 
`20 = 100 + 100 (resp 1) + 300 + 300(resp 3) + 400 ( resp3) = 1200?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @mark for making me realise what you meant. I think the following should be alittle more efficient

```sql
CREATE TABLE test
(
    `resp` Int64,
    `spot` Int64,
    `weight` Int64
)
ENGINE = Memory

INSERT INTO test VALUES (1,10,100),(2,10,200),(3,10,300),(1,10,100),(1,20,100),(3,20,300),(4,20,400),(1,30,100),(2,30,200),(3,30,300),(5,30,500)

SELECT
    min_spot AS spot,
    sum(sum(weight)) OVER (ORDER BY spot ASC) AS weight
FROM
(
    SELECT
        resp,
        min(spot) AS min_spot,
        argMin(weight, spot) AS weight
    FROM test
    GROUP BY resp
)
GROUP BY spot
```

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Your code should be really more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT spot, sum (sum (weight)) over (order by spot) as weigt
FROM 
(
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT 
  *
, row_number() over (partition by resp order by spot)
  as rn
FROM VALUES
(
  'resp UInt32, spot UInt32, weight UInt32'
, (1, 10, 100)
, (2, 10, 200)
, (3, 10, 300)
, (1, 10, 100)
, (1, 20, 100)
, (3, 20, 300)
, (4, 20, 400)
, (1, 30, 100)
, (2, 30, 200)
, (3, 30, 300)
, (5, 30, 500)
)
)
WHERE rn = 1
)
GROUP BY spot
```

The result is:

| spot | weigt |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 600 |
| 20 | 1000 |
| 30 | 1500 |

[fiddle](https://fiddle.clickhouse.com/3cc7947d-ce95-4de6-8792-b21a28f6bfaf)